# When in the view lifecycle does UITableViewCell create its outlets/labels/subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I am trying to create a `UIView` as a subview of a subclassed `UITableViewCell`. Essentially I want a view which is the same size as the cell, and sits between the cell's `contentView` and `backgroundView`.

I imagine that somewhere under the hood (possibly in `layoutSubviews`), there is a line in `UITableViewCell.m` something like:

```
if (self.contentView != nil) {
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
}
```

If I want to mimic the way Apple does it, where should I put this code in my own custom `UITableViewCell` subclass?

Also, in my first attempted implementation, the subview is displayed but it has the default cell height of 44px rather than the height I specified in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. There are also other small bugs that show up, which is why I'd like to try and replicate Apple's implementation rather than try my own semi-functional one.

EDIT: Here's my code so far:

In `CustomTableViewCell.h`

```
interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *newSubview;
@end
```

In `CustomTableViewCell.m`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.newSubview != nil) {
        self.newSubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self insertSubview:self.newSubview aboveSubview:self.backgroundView];
    }
}
```

In `tableViewController.m`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
myCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
cell.newSubview = view;
```

Comment: Show what you've tried so far, and have you set the auto-resizing rules?

Comment: Tried setting autoresizemask, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've posted my code. Thanks

Comment: Slightly off topic, but one thing I know-- the Autoresizing stuff from xib's or storyboards really mucks this stuff up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, objects should create their properties in their designated initializer, unless there is an overriding design principle (or a performance/resource issue) which mandates that they create them later.

The designated initializer for `UIView` (and `NSView` on OS X) is `-initWithFrame:`. The designated initializer for `UITableView` is `initWithFrame:style:`. Since a view will usually need to have it's visible subviews available immediately upon being added to its superview, it is fine to create and set them in the designated initializer.

`-layoutSubviews` is intended for updating the layout, which is to say the center, bounds (or frame) and (optionally) transform. Now, because of the ordering of messages. You don't want to create your subviews in `-layoutSubviews` because that method gets invoked repeatedly during the lifetime of your view, as its parent view's bounds changed and as it gets removed or re-added to its parent view, or as its subviews change.

In the case of UITableView, `-layoutSubviews` is called every time the table is reloaded.

A typical exception to this rule is the creation of `UITableViewCell`s used as rows of the table, which must be created dynamically.

The `-heightForRowAtIndexPath` method provides a table view with the amount of space it needs to leave for that row's cell, but doesn't actually cause the cell to be resized. YOu have to set the cell's bounds yourself when creating the cell (or the cell can set its own bounds in `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, if it's designed to be a fixed value). IF your cell's size does not match the table's expectations, you will get gaps or overlaps.

For autoresizing masks to work properly, you must configure the view's initial frame yourself (either in code or in a nib). Autoresizing a view affects how it responds to *changes* in its parent view's bounds, but does not help in determining the view's initial frame.

Specifically, you must set the initial frames for subviews of your cells (and also ensure sibling subview ordering, etc). This is easier to do in nibs than in code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.

So, given that in the designated initializer for my CustomTableViewCell, the subviews are not yet know, is it OK to use the `[insertSubview: aboveSubview:]` method in `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Absolutely. View hierarchies are designed to support dynamic manipulation. That's part of what makes them so wonderful. You can add and remove subviews whenever it suits you. However, managing the view hierarchy is conceptually rather different from managing the layout of your views. Perhaps there is a more natural place to add and remove views, in terms of whatever properties are being changed that cause you to want to add or remove views. For example, table views might add/remove subviews when their contents change (in -reloadData), and then lay them out in a separate step.

Comment: Also, my `newSubview` is incorrectly sized but the cell's `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` are correctly sized, even though all three were initialized in the same way: `initWithFrame:cell.frame`. This suggests that some of the views are resized after they have been created. Is it possible for me to replicate this process for my own custom cell view?

Comment: Well, I might be wrong about the content view size not being changed by the table view. One should always test one's assumptions!

Comment: Haha, this may be something that's worth investigating further. In the end, I decided to manually set the height of the subview when I create the reusable cell - a less elegant, but still workable solution.